# Offline Installation of R packages

Tags: r, package, offline, cran

My institute uses proxy server, and no one is able to install packages in a usual way. (i.e downloading binary file from CRAN and then choosing Mirro and the installing etc etc).

I am able to install packages if I use internet outside of my institute.

So, I am looking for an offline way to install packages. Please provide a detailed solution, I have just started using R.

Before writing this question I did look at this earlier asked question but did not quite understand the terms which have been used here (they are very direct). I am a newbie, please provide me a detailed solution.
[Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

Help will really be appreciated. I am really stuck here. I am not able to do anything.

Thank you.

Comment: So... you can't access the Internet at all? Because even with a proxy, you should still be able to download the binary from CRAN using your web browser, and unzip it.

Comment: What part of the answer to the linked question do you not understand specifically?

Comment: You can use port 81 which is always opened for normal mailing and inet. And secondly you could download the zip files from the R site or bioconductor.  And than install them with install.packages(c(pack1,pack2,pack3)) full zip names required!

Comment: @Roland Hi, let us say my package zip file's path is C:/Users/Desktop/thezipfile (eg C:/Users/Desktop/ggplot2_0.9.3.1), now how do I use these functions #######install.packages("ggplot2", contriburl="file:///path/to/packages/"),,,,,,,,ibrary(tools)
write_PACKAGES("/path/to/packages/")###### ? What is 'path' in this command? Is it "C:/Users/Desktop/thezipfile" for me?

Comment: Once you've downloaded the zip file, you don't actually need `install.packages`. You can just unzip it directly into your R library path (which will be c:\program files\R\R-<version>\library in a default installation).

Comment: If you're on windows, at least try `setInternet2()` and using the normal installation process first.

Comment: @HongOoi Thank you very much. Phew. Worked.

Answer (score 9):

This is my work around. Might be helpful for you too.

> **Idea:** Download packages with their dependencies through internet and install packages offline.

```
# Set Mirror to download packages    
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/")))

 # Set Working Directory   
    setwd(file.path(
        "D:"
      , "User"
      , "DownloadingPackagesWithDependencies"
      )
      )


getPackages <- function(packs){
  packages <- unlist(
      tools::package_dependencies(
          packs
        , available.packages()
        , which=c("Depends", "Imports")
        , recursive=TRUE
        )
      )
    packages <- union(packs, packages)
    packages
  }

# Specify Packages to Download with their dependencies also   
Packages <- getPackages(
                c(
                  "ggplot2"
                  )
                )


download.packages(
    pkgs=Packages
  , destdir=getwd()
  , type="source")

# Install packages from local drive
    install.packages(
        pkgs="ggplot2_0.9.3.1.tar.gz"
      , repos = NULL
      , type="source"
       )
```