# how can I offline install ggbiplot using windows

Tags: r

There are several solution for packages on Cran such as [Offline Installation of R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190103/offline-installation-of-r-packages)

and 
[Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

and many others, however, none could help me to install this package offline.

This is the link to the package 
https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot

this is what I did, first I go to http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html and downaload it and install this one offline then I dont know how to install the other package 
is there any comment ?

Comment: what happen if you execute `library(gbiplot)`?

Comment: @ mucio   Error in library(gbiplot) : there is no package called ‘gbiplot’ my problem is that i dont know how install this package which is not in Cran in an offline way!

Answer (score 0):

You need `devtools` for this, but if you have it try:

```
install("path/to/unzipped_pkg_zip_file")
```

Check also this question:
[Instal R packages from github downloading master.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366772/instal-r-packages-from-github-downloading-master-zip)