# R Error installing packages from local repository on Windows

Tags: r, dependencies, package, offline, install.packages

My Institution doesn't give me internet access on the computer I'm running R on. So I have to download packages with all dependencies on one PC and then install them from source on my work PC.

Downloading packages with dependencies worked fine using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190646/6400542) 
However, installing them with (e.g. for lavaan):

```
install.packages(pkgs = "lavaan_0.5-20.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

produces several warnings:

```
Warnung: ungültiges Paket 'lavaan_0.5-20.tar.gz'
Fehler: Fehler: keine Pakete angegeben
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\HIP\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "lavaan_0.5-20.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lavaan_0.5-20.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841614) and used

```
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES("C:/Users/HIP/Documents/R/R_packages")
```

then deleted the PACKAGES.gz (as suggested in a comment) and used

```
install.packages(pkgs="lavaan", type="source", 
contriburl="file:///C:/Users/HIP/Documents/R/R_packages")
```

and it gave me the following warnings:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Der Servername oder die Serveradresse konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Der Servername oder die Serveradresse konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Der Servername oder die Serveradresse konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Der Servername oder die Serveradresse konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HIP/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lavaan’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)
```

Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem? Your help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, it somehow sent the ask while I was still editing it.

Answer (score 1):

On linux mint I solved the problem by writing the whole path (starting with /home/...) to the tar.gz-file. If the working directory is the directory with the tar.gz-file, this can be achieved by

```
install.packages(pkgs= paste(getwd(),"/lavaan_0.5-20.tar.gz",sep=""), repos = NULL, type ="source")
```