# Offline installation of R

Tags: r, offline

`install.packages()` while installing packages, keeps the downloaded files temporarily in the directory specified in the flag `destdir`.
After the installation of a new package (& dependencies) is complete, all downloaded packages are deleted from this directory automatically. Is it possible that these downloaded packages do not get deleted so that I can take the bundle in other machines in the classroom and install from local directory without connecting to Internet?

Comment: What's with the downvotes and close votes? This is definitely not too broad, is a good and answerable question. Please DO comment when casting a close vote and/or a downvote. Now, if you tell me this is a duplicate I will agree, but definitely not too broad...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline install of R package and dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

Answer (score 4):

Download the packages and use the following:
    `install.packages("your package", contriburl="file:///path/to/packages/")` 
as explained in [Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks. The reply at 'Offline install of R package' as referred by you was a little incomplete. I have added to it and now the installation works.