# Installing R Add On Packages without CRAN

Tags: linux, r

I am posting this question after reading and attempting the suggestions mentioned at :-

[Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies/30214367#302143)

I am looking to create a Local package repository for installing tar.gz packages in a Linux R server instance .

I have followed the instructions exactly as mentioned in this post :-

```
Step 1 - Downloaded all R packages to the source destination on Linux. 

Step 2 - Used library(tools) write_PACKAGES("/path/to/packages/") This created 2 files in /path/to/packages/ :- PACKAGES and PACKAGES.GZ 

Step 3 - Launched R (v 3.2.0) and ran this command :- install.packages("ggplot2", contrib.url="file:///path/to/packages/")
```

However, the CRAN Menu (which prompts for selecting a CRAN mirror) pops up. I was under the impression that it will not. When I proceed to select a repository and hit Okay,I get the following error message :-

Error in `download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : unused argument (contrib.url = "path/to/packages/")`

Can someone, please help.

Comment: a) It is called CRAN, not CRANE. Edited in three places.  b) This has been asked and answered several times. c) For local installs you do NOT need a local repo. Point to files directly.  d) Look at [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) for easy local repos if you think you need one.

Answer (score 1):

From the help of `install.packages` (which you can access using `?install.packages`) you can see that the correct argument name is `contriburl` without the dot.

Apparently you should use it as:

```
contriburl = contrib.url("file:///pathToYourFiles/")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nico - install.packages("ggplot2", contriburl = (contrib.url="file:///pathToYourFiles/")) did the trick .