# offline installation of packages in R - empty index file generated

Tags: r, installation, r-package

I am trying to install packages on a remote windows machine with no internet connection using source packages. I am trying to follow the instructions given in an answer to the previous question

[Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

I have a folder with .tar.gz files for the package and it's dependencies. I run the commands

```
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES()
```

which generates the `PACKAGES` and `PACKAGES.gz` in the same folder. However, my PACKAGES file is empty (with size 0 KB).

When I try to install the package using

```
install.packages("<PACKAGE_NAME>", contriburl = "file:///")
```

(I am in the same directory as all the source files), I am getting the following error

```
cannot open compressed file '//PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the way I specify the path or is it because my `PACKAGES` file is empty that I am getting this error.

Any help here would be great!

Additional info - The remote machine is a Windows machine and I have also tried deleting the PACKAGES.gz file before installing (as recommended in the link above), but did not succeed.

Thanks!

SN248

Comment: When I'm installing from local  source I use `repo=NULL`. and of course I have a proper toolchain in place. (You said nothing about the second aspect.)

Comment: @42- Thanks for your comment. I am not sure I know about the proper toolchain. Could you elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: You can download windows binaries using the `type` argument in `download.packages`. This may be the easiest way to go. Take a look at the help file for more details.

Comment: This quest remains too vague. Please read [MCVE] and use the [edit] facilities to improve the question body. I don't really understand the configuration of a "remote" machine with "no Internet connection". No specifics about the packages or R versions are offered. No error messages are reported. No effort at looking up terms you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the package that I wanted (package name = `dplyr`), using the hints in the comments above. I needed to change two things

1. I downloaded windows binaries instead of `source` files, using `type = "win.binary"` parameter in the `download.packages` command.
2. The path in `contriburl = "file:///"` needed to be changed to `contriburl = "file:///<ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_WIN_BINARIES>"`

With these changes, the package installation went successfully.

Hope it helps others.

SN248