# Using R offline - problems with indexing and version

Tags: r

Really hope somebody is able to help please.

We have a need to run R in an environment which has no access to the internet.

So, working in an online environment, I used the R commands:

```
pkg.list = available.packages()
download.packages(pkgs = pkg.list, destdir = "C:\\MyRPackages")
```

to download current packages.  These were downloaded as `tar.gz` files.  I transferred these to the environment where internet isn't available.

I then tried this command (following advice in [Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)):

```
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES()
```

to 'index' the packages.  This doesn't seem to work, as it didn't create PACKAGES and PACKAGES.gz which it was meant to.

Funnily enough, this worked when I tried with a couple of packages which were .zip files, so figured there is some reason that R cannot recognize the tar.gz files.  But in any case, when I tried:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", contriburl="file:///path/to/packages/")
```

I had an error message saying that the current version of R didn't support these packages.

So I seem to have a two-fold problem:

- issue about using the Write_PACKAGES command
- issue about version history

Would be grateful for any advice on this please.

Answer (score 1):

> These were downloaded as `tar.gz` files.

This appears to be a bug or at least unexpected behaviour in `download.packages`. The documentation for that function says

> `type`
>   character string, indicate which type of packages: see install.packages.

and on Windows, `install.packages` with no `type` specified will download binary rather than source files.

To get around this, you can manually specify `type="win.binary"` in your `download.packages` call:

```
download.packages(pkgs = pkg.list, destdir = "C:\\MyRPackages", type="win.binary")
```

Once you've done that, you should have a directory of zip files which are your packages. You can then install them with

```
install.packages("pkgname_x.x-x.zip", repos=NULL)  # not contriburl
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks.....I didn't realize but that has already helped enormously.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries. If this helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting it so others can see it.

Comment: Sure will do...but sorry I'm new to this, how do I upvote/accept it?

Comment: Click on the triangles to the left of the answer to upvote/downvote. Click on the tick mark to accept it.