# R: How do I install packages and dependencies offline

Tags: r, repository, libraries, offline, cran

Firstly, I am aware of the other post on the topic, but it does not resolve my problem.

[Offline install of R package and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies)

I need to install a number of packages on an offline Ubuntu machine, but the dependencies keep messing up.

First I download all packages and dependencies using the following code (on an online ubuntu machine):

```
# Loading library
library(tools)

# Function for downloading packages and dependencies
getPackages <- function(packs){
  packages <- unlist(
    tools::package_dependencies(packs, available.packages(),
                                which=c("Depends", "Imports"), recursive=TRUE)
  )
  packages <- union(packs, packages)
  packages
}

# Determining what packages to download
packages <- getPackages(c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC", "fasttime", "tidyr", "knitr", "randomForest", "RMySQL", "jsonlite"))

# Downloading packages
download.packages(pkgs = packages, destdir = "/path/to/packages/")

# Writing files such that this folder can be used as a repository
write_PACKAGES("/path/to/packages/")
```

Second I install the packages on an offline machine with the following commands, as found in the linked post.

```
# Installs local packages
install.packages(c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC", "fasttime", "tidyr", "knitr", "randomForest", "RMySQL", "jsonlite"), contriburl = "file:///path/to/packages/")
```

What happens is that the installation works on a few packages and then crashes with the messages.

```
ERROR: dependency ‘dplyr’ is not available for package ‘tidyr’
* removing ‘/home/h52z/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘dplyr’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/h52z/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC",  :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC",  :
  installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC",  :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems that the installer cannot handle the dependencies despite creating a local repository using the **tools** library. It will be a lot of work, having to find out myself in which order the packages should be installed.

Do you have any suggestions? Do I have to get into tools like **miniCRAN**, or do I need to downloade the entire CRAN repository as in the example in the other link?

Comment: are all these packages up to date ? (I think I can infer that they are from your question but to be sure)

Comment: The linked post suggests using `contriburl="file:///path/to/packages/"`, not `contriburl="/path/to/packages/"`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Argh, sorry, I will just edit the post, as I already did use file:. Yeah, the packages are up to date, as they are downloaded from CRAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest `miniCRAN` and specifically the `pkgDep` function to take care of all the dependency stuff. For example

```
library(miniCRAN)

pkgs <- c("tidyverse", "data.table", "RODBC", "RJDBC", "fasttime", "tidyr", 
    "knitr", "randomForest", "RMySQL", "jsonlite")
pkgList <- pkgDep(pkgs, type = "source", suggests = FALSE)
makeRepo(pkgList, path="/path/to/packages/", type = c("source"))
```

And then you would install from the repo with

```
install.packages(pkgs, repos="file://path/to/packages/", type="source")
```

Comment: Does the installation the just work as in my post, where I just refer to the contriburl?

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt I've updated to show that you would set the `repos=` parameter when installing after you've created the miniCRAN repo. More details at the [miniCRAN introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html)