# PortfolioAnalytics error while creating efficient frontier

Tags: r, optimization, plugins, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I'm trying to run portfolio optimization problems, everything runs smoothly, except when I try to create the efficient frontier.

I've tried to mess around with all the function parameters, I've installed all packages and plugins recommended by the documentation. But even when I try to run the code in the efficient frontier demo in the package's GitHub repository I get the same error message. I suspect it is a missing plugin or an error in the recommended packages installation. Can someone at least give me a hint on whats going on?

The code I have is pretty simple, but my main conclusion is that I don't have any problems in it since I get the same error while running the code located in: https://github.com/R-Finance/PortfolioAnalytics/blob/master/demo/demo_efficient_frontier.R

my code:

```
base_pf <- portfolio.spec(colnames(monthly_returns_with_rf[,-selic_col]))

base_pf <- add.constraint(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'full_investment')

base_pf <- add.constraint(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'long_only')

moments <- set.portfolio.moments(monthly_returns_with_rf[,-selic_col], portfolio = base_pf, method = 'boudt', k = 3)

base_pf <- add.constraint(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'box', min = 0, max = 0.4)

base_pf <- add.objective(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'return', name = 'mean')

base_pf <- add.objective(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'risk', name = 'var')

ef_fr <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=monthly_returns_with_rf[,-selic_col], portfolio=base_pf, type="mean-StdDev", match.col = 'StdDev')

opt_base <- optimize.portfolio(monthly_returns_with_rf[,- selic_col], portfolio = base_pf, optimize_method = 'ROI')
print(opt_base)
```

th error message I get is:

```
Error in maxret_opt(R = R, constraints = constraints, moments = moments, : paste0("package:", plugin) %in% search() || requireNamespace(plugin,  .... is not TRUE
Traceback:

1. create.EfficientFrontier(R = monthly_returns_with_rf[, -selic_col], 
 .     portfolio = base_pf, type = "mean-StdDev", match.col = "StdDev")
2. meanvar.efficient.frontier(portfolio = portfolio, R = R, n.portfolios = n.portfolios, 
 .     risk_aversion = risk_aversion, ... = ...)
3. optimize.portfolio(R = R, portfolio = portfolio, optimize_method = "ROI", 
 .     ... = ...)
4. maxret_opt(R = R, constraints = constraints, moments = moments, 
 .     target = target, solver = solver, control = control)
5. stopifnot(paste0("package:", plugin) %in% search() || 
requireNamespace(plugin, 
 .     quietly = TRUE))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Yes i solved the problem installing ROI.plugin.glpk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can trace the error back to find what caused it. From your error message, the function that causes this error is the `maxret_opt()` function. This is a function called by `optimize.portfolio()`, as you can see from the steps, likewise `optimize.portfolio()` is called by `meanvar.efficient.frontier()`, itself called by `create.EfficientFrontier()`, which is from your script.

Now to the error. Looking at the source code of the `maxret_opt()` function, I find the following:

```r
function (R, moments, constraints, target, solver = "glpk", 
  control = NULL) 
{
  stopifnot("package:ROI" %in% search() || requireNamespace("ROI", 
    quietly = TRUE))
  plugin <- paste0("ROI.plugin.", solver)
  stopifnot(paste0("package:", plugin) %in% search() || requireNamespace(plugin, 
    quietly = TRUE))
```

The `solver` argument is passed as "glpk". The object `plugin` is saved as the a string by concatenating the strings "ROI.plugin." and "glpk" (saved in `solver`). The `search()` function returns attached packages, in the form of "package:PerformanceAnalytics". That is why in the `stopifnot()` call, "package:" is concatenated with the string in plugin, which gives the string "package:ROI.plugin.glpk". This is then checked if this string is among the strings returned by `search()`, it also tries to attach the package with the `|| requireNamespace(plugin, quietly = TRUE))`. If the string isn't in the attached packages, it uses the string to attach the package. If both of these fail, then the function is stopped.

Therefore, you need to install the `ROI.plugin.glpk` package. You should also install `ROI.plugin.quadprog`. I installed both and the example efficient frontier works for me. This is a long winded answer, but hopely you can learn how to debug errors in the future using the logic above.

Comment: I'm not an avid programmer, so I'm not really sure how to traceback errors this deeply. But I found that the `ROI.plugin.glpk`package is missing. Even after installing it using `install.packages('ROI.plugin.glpk')`. Another issue to keep me up at night!  Thank you very much for this, I appreciate you taking the time to elaborate.

Comment: Check your CRAN mirrors. In the meantime, You can download the package directly here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROI.plugin.glpk/index.html, then install it manually on your pc. Use this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies) to find out how to do that.