# How no more install y/n prompts in R for unsupervised experimentation?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am testing most of the models caret supports on a bunch of PCs. Unfortunately caret "suggested" packages do not include most of the model packages available to caret. Every time a new version of R comes out I have to sit in front of each PC and wait for each prompt to press the 1 button and Enter. Is there an option I could set to tell R or Rstudio to just install anything asked for? A for every a/s/n prompt too.

```
list.of.packages <- c("caretEnsemble","logicFS"," RWeka","ordinalNet","xgboost","mlr","caret","MLmetrics","bartMachine","spikeslab","party","rqPen","monomvn","foba","logicFS","rPython","qrnn","randomGLM","msaenet","Rborist","relaxo","ordinalNet","rrf","frbs","extraTrees","ipred","elasticnet","bst","brnn","Boruta","arm","elmNN","evtree","extraTrees","deepnet","kknn","KRLS","RSNNS","partDSA","plsRglm","quantregForest","ranger","inTrees")


new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages, dep = TRUE)


install.packages("mlr", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

Code I went with:

```
 list.of.packages <-getModelInfo(allmodel)[[1]]$library;
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])];
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages, dep = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
getPackages <- function(packs){
  packages <- unlist(
    tools::package_dependencies(packs, available.packages(),
                                which=c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"), # 
                                recursive=TRUE)
  )
  packages <- union(packs, packages)
  packages
}

packages <- getPackages(c("caret")) # add in other packages you want here
install.packages(packages)
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15650828/6619250 allows you to install all dependencies (recursively) from "Depends", "Imports", and "Suggests"

**However**, actually trying out this code results in a list of **959** (!!) packages because of the list of 'Suggests' packages.

Hence, I would advice you to take a look at [the list of "Suggests" packages in CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/) and replace `caret` with your own list, which you will have to do go through yourself to determine which packages you want.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not really work for me. Or rather I already have a list and install caret's suggests too. But caret adds algorithms with new packages.

Comment: what sort of new packages does it add?

Comment: packages ・RWeka・ rPython・ are not available (for version..)

Comment: but they will still be asked for  every pass through the models list. And caret does not always add the necessary packages to "suggests". As you saw recursive suggests seems like it DLs the entire CRAN archive.

Comment: getModelInfo()$adaboost$library So how do I use a variable instead of $adaboost$?

Comment: according to [the caret documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-76/topics/modelLookup), `getModelInfo` is meant to provide you with additional information (e.g. functions, metadata) associated with a model. the documentation suggests using `checkInstall()` to check if the packages needed are installed

Comment: Code I went with:           list.of.packages <-getModelInfo(allmodel)[[1]]$library;
          new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])];
          if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages, dep = TRUE);   ::should I make this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

run it from .bat

"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH ULTIMATESTACKING3skippingMCandUS.R

and add

options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/")))

to beginning of R file