# How to install a R package from local folder with the dependencies installation still in same folder?

Tags: r, r-package

Due to the poor network condition I have to install R package from a folder in my disk. In this folder All of the source archives are included(I mirror it by wget from other place).

I have read the post [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

However that method only work in situation which all the dependencies are already satisfied. However it is difficult. When there is one package which is necessary is missed, the installation will roll-back.

All the source archive names in the local folder is identical as it in CRAN.

Is there any way to make it automatically install dependent package from local folder?

or if it is difficult, Is there any way to install the package locally without dependency checking?

If they are both difficult, is there any official solution toward local offline package installation?

Finally, is there special requirement of the structure of local folder?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Does this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281322/only-download-sources-of-a-package-and-all-dependencies?noredirect=1&lq=1 also of any help?

Comment: @hpesoj626, please forgive my poor search skill, I didn't find this link even if I attempt for several times. The first link is able to solve my problem, however the second seems more advanced I will have a further hacking on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, @MartinSVictory. I'm glad to have linked you to the right solution.